# LewisSbond error in xymtex

Tags: xymtex

I have the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}   
\usepackage{xymtex}   
\begin{document}   
\LewistetrahedralB{0==C;1==A;2==B;3==X;4==Y} \\   
\LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1T==A;2T==B;3T==X;4T==Y}   
\end{document}
```

But when typesetting, I got the error like this

[image]

And when I delete the line

```
\LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1T==A;2T==B;3T==X;4T==Y}
```

Then everything will be ok.

[image]

I don't know what's the problem here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that \verticalpair in lewisstruc.sty
shoud be changed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{xymtex}
%%
\def\verticalpair{\vbox{%
%\dotnodimension % change this line
\hbox{\dotnodimension}
\nointerlineskip
\kern0.3em
%\dotnodimension}} % change this line
\hbox{\dotnodimension}}}
%%
\begin{document}
\LewistetrahedralB{0==C;1==A;2==B;3==X;4==Y} \\
\LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1T==A;2T==B;3T==X;4T==Y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add an screenshot of your result to your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much, everything 's fine now.